# External Monitor issues in Windows 7 BootCamp MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, external-display

So I got a monitor to use as an external for my MacBook Pro. It is an LG e2340 and I am connecting via HDMI by the way. Anyways, there are some issues I have found and I am wondering if there are any ways to remedy them.

- In the mid-resolution range (1000horizontal-1600h) green lines appear in the dark areas of the external screen
- In the high-resolution range(1600h-1900h) it seems like the monitor can't handle it because it is all black and the menu buttons don't work.

I tried to see how it fared in OSX and most of the same things were happening. I tried the 1080p option and it did the blank screen thing. Then I tried 1080i and what do you know it worked. I looked up what the i meant and found that it was interlaced so I went back to windows and looked through the advanced resolution options and found options for 1920x1080 (Interlaced) and it worked.

Things I have noticed though are that the refresh rate is only 30Hz so I can sometimes notice flickering, especially with Windows Glass.

So, after all of that, what do you think is wrong? Is there a way to increase refresh rate with interlaced? Or even better, how can I get 1080p to work?

Thanks a bunch

EDIT: It works with 720p so its not that its not capable of progressive. On the web page [here](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-E2340V-PN-led-monitor) it says Full HD 1080p = YES

Comment: What model year is this MacBook Pro?

Comment: It is a 2011 15"

Comment: What are you using to connect the MBP to the TV (specifically, what kind of cable and adapter)? Are they Apple branded, or are they generic?

Comment: It is a generic mini port to hdmi cable

Comment: Have you tried official Apple adapters or other cables? I'm thinking this is because you have a bum cable that can't sustain high data rates.

Comment: No I havent because the official ones, I heard, are expensive. I could try looking into other cables though

Comment: Not sure what your price range or desired length are, so here's a [10ft MiniDP to HDMI](http://amzn.to/JAZwFd), and if you already have an HDMI cable here's a [cheap adapter](http://amzn.to/JB03qA) or a [less fishy looking adapter](http://amzn.to/JB0cug).

Comment: I actually have that same cord, just its the 15 ft version. Same company

Comment: It's probably a bad cable. This problem does not seem like a graphics card issue. It seems like the cable. If you can't return the cable, try it with other TVs; if you can borrow a friend's cable, try it with your MBP and TV. See if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I tried it with other tv's same problem. Ordered a new one and it works great. Must have just been a faulty cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a bad cable. Read the above comments for the discussion.